# Apply filter to kendo-ui dropdown list

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, angular5, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to apply the filter to the kendo ui dropdown list. 
[Here already provided the example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/dropdownlist/filtering/)

However my data source is a string array instead of an array likes

```
public data: Array<{ text: string, value: number }>;
```

My data is

```
public data: string[] = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];
```

So I modified the code from the link

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <kendo-dropdownlist
    #list
    [data]="data"
    [filterable]="true"
  >
 </kendo-dropdownlist>

 })
 export class AppComponent {
@ViewChild("list") list;

public source: Array<string> = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'];

public data: Array<string>;

constructor() {
    this.data = this.source.slice();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  // need code here
    .subscribe(x => {
        this.data = x;
        this.list.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

What I want is the code inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, I use angular 5 and rxjs 5.5. It seems not working with the code.

```
this.list.filterChange.asObservable().pipe(
        switchMap(value => from([this.source]).pipe(
            tap(() => this.list.loading = true),
            delay(1000),
            map((data) => data.filter(contains(value)))
        ))
    )
```

Comment: You are not following their example; why did you remove `textField` and `valueField` from `kendo-dropdownlist` in the HTML?  Those fields are required, I'm fairly sure.  You also need `export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit ` and `import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';` for that function to run.

Comment: @xinthose, don't think so. If you look at the [example--Basic Usage](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/). They use `public listItems: Array<string> = [
        'Baseball', 'Basketball', 'Cricket', 'Field Hockey',
        'Football', 'Table Tennis', 'Tennis', 'Volleyball'
    ];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I made was removing s.text in the contains predicate.  Hope this helps.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
   const contains = value => s =>
   s.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) !== -1;

  this.list.filterChange
  .asObservable()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(value =>
      from([this.source]).pipe(
        tap(() => (this.list.loading = true)),
        delay(1000),
        map(data => data.filter(contains(value)))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(x => {
    this.data = x;
    this.list.loading = false;
  });
 }
```

Comment: Did you really try it on Stackblitz?

Comment: yes, certified works on my computer.  Im guessing it's still not working for you?

Comment: Can you put a stackbiltz link for me please?